# How to find control image button inside repeater, which is already inside a datalist

Tags: asp.net, repeater, imagebutton, datalist

How to find control (i.e image button) inside repeater, that repeater is already in a datalist? because I have to perform delete operation on that image button.

Here is my code, here I'm getting repeater but not image button:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in Dlist_SearchResult.Controls)
            {

                rptrResult = (Repeater)item.FindControl("Rptr_result");

                imgbtnDelete = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("imgbtnDelete");


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Recursion in your FindControl. FindControl by default is not recursive.

Try this:

```
private static Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootCtrl, string ID)
{
    if (rootCtrl.ID == ID)
        return rootCtrl;

    foreach (Control ctr in rootCtrl.Controls)
    {
        Control foundCtl = FindControlRecursive(ctr, ID);
        if (foundCtl != null)
            return foundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

you can call it

```
Button btn = FindControlRecursive((Control)Page,"imgbtnDelete");
```